# Create a gist using GitHub API

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, gist

I wanna create a gist using GitHub API. I tried an POST ajax request:

```
var gist = {
    "description": "Avatars",
    "public": true,
    "files": {
        "check.txt": {
            "content": "Avatars list..."
        }
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(gist),
    success: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.error("Error!: ", e);
    }
});
```

But I always get the following error:

```
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST https://api.github.com/gists 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: PS: I got the code from: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5o88k6/is_it_possible_to_post_user_input_to_a_pastebin/

Comment: You need to supply credentials when making the call in order to show who you are and prove you have access. See the 'Authentication' section of your link: https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#authentication

Answer (score 3):

When you want to edit things on Github, you need to authorize your request. Either by adding a username and password to the request or an oauth token.

More information can be found in the authorization documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/

Comment: can you please provide example or link to docs, where it shows how `username` and `pass` parameters should be binded

Answer (score 1):

Since I ran across the same problem recently, let me add the examples requested by T.Todua

If you want to authenticate with username and password, add the following lines to your $.ajax request:

```
crossDomain: true,
beforeSend: function (XHR) {
  XHR.setRequestHeader(
    'Authorization','Basic ' + btoa(Username + ':' + Password)
  );
},
```

If, however, you created an access token for your gists (see [Github help](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) and don't forget to check the "Gist" permission!) then add the following lines instead

```
crossDomain: true,
headers: {
  'Authorization':'bearer ' + GitHubAccessToken
},
```

The GitHubAccessToken will be shown once (and only once!) immediately after creation, so make sure to store it in a safe location as everybody knowing this access token will be able to modify your gists (until you revoke it again).